# mysqli_connect works but not $mysqli->real_connect

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli, xampp

I'm running in an issue with `$mysqli->real_connect` . `new mysqli` is working fine but `$mysqli->real_connect` brings the following error message.
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on bool`

I don't finde realy much information about `$mysqli->real_connect`. Anny suggestion what i can do?

```php
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_init();

$hostaddress = 'xxxxxxx.xxxx';
$db = "xxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxx";
$port = "xxxxx";
$pass = "xxxxxxxxx";
    
    
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
$mysqli->ssl_set( "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" , NULL, NULL );
    
$conn = $mysqli->real_connect( $hostaddress, $username, $pass, $db, $port );
$conn=             new mysqli( $hostaddress, $username, $pass, $db, $port );

?>
```

Solution:

```php
<?php

$conn = mysqli_init();

$hostaddress = 'xxxxxxx.xxxx';
$db = "xxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxx";
$port = "xxxxx";
$pass = "xxxxxxxxx";
    
    
$conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
$conn->ssl_set( "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" , NULL, NULL );
    
$conn->real_connect( $hostaddress, $username, $pass, $db, $port );


?>
```

Comment: Any reason why you are creating another new mysqli object at the end?  Looks like mysqli exposes some variables for you to see why the connection failed with real_connect: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php.   The return value of real_connect is a boolean, you're just supposed to keep using the `$mysqli` object to perform queries.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the information. I just added the second $conn for showing what i put instead for testing. Below works fine but the upper $conn is not working.

Comment: Where did you get this idea, `$conn = $mysqli->real_connect`? What does $conn to do here, given you already created a mysqli instance?

Comment: I'm noob thank you for the tip "Your Common Sense 2". Removed $mysqli and put everywhere $conn